# How do I add another composition

Tags: composition, melody, noteflight

For my music class, we had to make a minor melody and a major melody. For the final project, we have to put these together in ABA format, so either major-minor-major or minor-major-minor. In noteflight, I made my major melody, so I need to switch to my minor, but I don't know how. How do I add another melody

Comment: Are you asking about how to use NoteFlight or about how to combine to major and minor melodies conceptually?

Comment: How to use noteflight. I have a minor melody. I just don't know how to put it in noteflight

Comment: Do you just want to know how to change key signatures in Noteflight?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Are you looking for strategies about how to modulate? Please edit to explain what exactly "adding another melody" means to you, and what kind of help you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple, well-used ways to consider. Either use *relative* keys or *parallel* keys. As in, if the 1st movement was in C maj., the middle part would be in A minor (relative) or, if 1st movement was in C maj., the middle part would be in C *minor* (parallel).

With each, the sonic change is not catastrophic - it flows nicely - and getting back to replaying the A section again will sound quite smooth.

There are, of course, other options, but those have been tried and tested over hundreds of years, so obviously work well!

Comment: I already have my minor melody. I just don't know to add it under my major in noteflight

Comment: @Matthew - exact opposite to what the question says! However, simply swap the ideas over. Or change the key for the middle section to reflect those ideas. Or is it use of Noteflight that's the problem? Not asked in the question. In which case, please clarify.